# Way to sync production and testing databases

Tags: c#, .net, sql, vb.net, sql-server-2005

I need to sync the data of a ms-sql 2005 & 2008 server to my development server (mssql 2005 & 2008).

The problem is I can't create .bak files, no permissions (to access the network share where the backup is saved).
The problem is not that I may not view the data (I have complete read access to the production server). I can also backup data to csv files and read them in on my system, but that's rather painful (encoding, foreign key reference constraints, having to do it for every table, etc...).  The problem is that the admin has no time to set  me the necessary permissions (he has larger problems...).

How can I still sync the data to my development server ?
I need some kind of syncing to a file, then transport anyhow (manual by FTP if necessary), and then update my development database. I've already tried backing up to a back file on a network share, but that doesn't work either.

I don't mind if I have to code a bit in my free time, but I really don't want to do all the low level stuff myself, like resolving constraint dependencies.

While I am at it, it would be great if I could merge data from several production servers on my development machine.

Any ideas or pointers ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the project http://sqlinserter.codeplex.com/.

It creates scipts in the form insert into table1 (col1,col2) values (1,2)

Comment: Does it also create the schema and resolve referential constraints ? I guess not. Then it's just as good as reading every table into a dataset and saving said dataset as XML. Hmmm, I gess I could drop all constrains and maybe add them again later.

Comment: It does not create the schema. But it is able to help with RI. Anyway a better way is offcourse to disable constraints.

Comment: Oh, of course, constraints can be disabled - makes sense - well somewhat. Had I known this beforehand...

Answer (score 2):

Check out sql data compare:

http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Data_Compare/

This is what we use when we have to sync databases.

Comment: I have no permissions to install software on the production server. That is a good policy and that will and also should stay that way. However, I can run software that doesn't need installation.

Comment: I think you only need to install it onto a computer that can access both databases.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  It only needs to access the server not be installed on it.

Comment: The production server runs under Citrix in a datacenter. I can't simultanously access both databases, and that's the problem I need to solve. If that wasn't the case, I would simply use the import/export data feature in SQL management studio and sync to my local database. No need for redgate whatever for this.

Answer (score 1):

Redgate sql compare does the job, but costs a bunch of bucks http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Compare/

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at the [RedGate SQL Data Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Data_Compare/index.htm) tool.

Answer (score 1):

What are you testing? Unless you're doing performance or integration tests, production data won't be very useful since it contains a whole lot of generic cases (which repeat millions of times) and few corner cases.

Therefore, I rarely sync those two. What I do is: I have a development database (a set of SQL files) which the first test sets up. This contains artificial test data plus data which caused bugs in production. To make this useful, the test database is as small as possible.

Then we have an integration test system which is simply a mirror of the production database. This is used for performance tests and some big, automatic tests but not for unit testing.

Comment: Artificial data is not good enough. I need to have real-life data, for reporting and testing the rendering and design also. For example to see how large columns are/need to be and whether the reported results are in fact correct, and testing for all sorts of possible null values, including the ones you get when you concatenate a string in SQL 2008. Artificial data is not good enough for that.

Comment: @Quandary: How can you be sure to get null values at all possible places if you don't hand-craft the test data?

Comment: Good point, what I really mean is doing the minimum work that it works with the production data ,-))

Comment: @Quandary: My point, exactly. If you just copy the production data, you will get something of dubious quality (at least from a testing point of view). That's why I build my own test cases plus I have a small tool which can copy tiny data sets from the production system when bugs are reports. Of course, you can copy all the test cases from production but my argument is to copy wisely instead of greedily.

Answer (score 0):

Your administrator doesn't have regular backups scheduled for the production database?

READ permission is not sufficient to backup a database. You won't be able to get indexes, relationships, or stored procedures without the BACKUP DATABASE permission.

You don't need these permissions if the administrator can simply grant you access to the backup files. If there are not backup files of your production database, he could have MUCH MUCH bigger problems in the future.

Comment: There are backup files, but I don't have access permission to them. The problem is he has no time, not even to do something as simple as set me a few permissions.

Comment: Hm. Well, at least the schemas are the same for each database, correct? I suppose you could try something like INSERT INTO [db1].[table_n] SELECT * FROM [db2].[table_n] for each of your tables...

Comment: Yes I could do that if db1 wasn't on a citrix server in a datacenter and db2 on my local machine. The problem is I need to transfer the data as some sort of file via sftp to my local computer.